# Fill a pandas dataframe by counting strings in a array and adding their values from a array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

1) numpy array **`r`** which consists of strings.

```
import numpy as np
r = np.array([['S', 'S'],['S', 'V1'],['S', 'V2'],['V1', 'S'],['V1', 'V1']])
```

2) numpy array **`acc`** conatin values. The first value refers to the first element of two dimensional array **`r`** and second value refers to the second element of two dimensional array **`r`**

```
acc = np.array([0.613,0.387])
```

3) **Question:** I want to fill dataframe df1. For example: Row1) Array **`r[0]=['S', 'S']`** contains 'S' in both then fill `S`=0.613+0.387=1.0 in df1 and `V1` and `V2` in df1 will zero as they do not exist in the array. Row2) Array **`r[1]=['S', 'V1']`** contains one 'S' then fill `S`=0.613  and `V1=0.387` in df1,and `V2=0` (does not exist).......and so on.

**Desired output:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'S':[1,0.613,0.613,0.387,0], 'V1': [0,0.387,0,0.613,1],'V2': [0,0,0.387,0,0]})
print(df1)  

        S     V1     V2
0  1.000  0.000  0.000
1  0.613  0.387  0.000
2  0.613  0.000  0.387
3  0.387  0.613  0.000
4  0.000  1.000  0.000
```

Comment: i think your expect output is wrong

Comment: why does desired output line #3 have `V2==1`, while on the step `1` it's `['V1', 'S']` ?

Comment: I have edited the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You can stack the dataframe, map the values and pivot back:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(r).stack().reset_index(name='val')

s['level_1'] = acc[s['level_1']]

s.pivot_table(index='level_0', 
              columns='val', 
              values='level_1', 
              aggfunc='sum', 
              fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
val          S     V1     V2
level_0                     
0        1.000  0.000  0.000
1        0.613  0.387  0.000
2        0.613  0.000  0.387
3        0.387  0.613  0.000
4        0.000  1.000  0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html),[`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df=pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(r),prefix='',prefix_sep='')
s=pd.Series(acc,index=range(1,len(acc)+1))

final=(pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(s.get)(np.where(df.eq(1),df.cumsum(axis=1),df)),
            columns=df.columns).groupby(df.columns,axis=1).sum())
```

---

```
       S     V1     V2
0  1.000  0.000  0.000
1  0.613  0.387  0.000
2  0.613  0.000  0.387
3  0.387  0.613  0.000
4  0.000  1.000  0.000
```